# Google chrome print preview alignment issues, css media print

Tags: css, google-chrome, debugging, printing, preview

we're using @media print css to style our print pages.  Now, when in Chrome and trying to print preview and the actual printed page, the alignment is off, resulting in the right 1/3 of the page being cut off.

The strange thing is, when you use any other browser, or even go into Chrome's rendering to "emulate media -> print", the page is rendered perfectly.

I've tried all kinds of playing with different containers, classes and ids, messing with flexible widths but the only thing that seems to work in hard-coding in a pixel width.  Even though this "fixes" the print preview for chrome, it breaks it for the other browsers that seem to be working.

I'm just not sure where else to look.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that Google Chrome wasn't accounting for margins.

Don't ask me why, but when in print preview you select Margins: None, the page fits inside.

Good luck to all who come across this problem.